# Execute (javascript) code every 10 seconds but start on 0 seconds too

Tags: javascript, html, timer, setinterval

I want to execute code every 10 seconds, but after first click. I mean I want the code to execute when a visitor clicks anywhere on the page in the beginning and then every 10 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.onclick= function(){
        window.open('http://www.google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 5, top = 5');
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="button" onclick="">
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I desperately need this code.

Comment: You want to open a new window every 10 seconds?

Comment: There is [*setInterval*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) and [*setTimeout*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Comment: search for setInterval

Comment: Are you trying to display ads every 10 seconds..?

Comment: thank for all
 blex ==> yes
 Derek 朕會功夫 ==> yes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    window.open('google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 5, top = 5');
}
document.body.onclick=function() {
    document.body.onclick = null; // Disable the onclick
    doSomething();
    setInterval(doSomething, 10000);
}
```

The second parameter to setInterval is the time in milliseconds, which is why I passed in 10000 (10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds).

The first parameter is the function you want to execute. You can also use an anonymous function, which is better for passing in arguments:

```
setInterval(function() { doSomething(); }, 10000);
```

---

To address the author's request in the comments, the following code will open a popup window when the document is clicked, then "refresh" it 5 times every 10 seconds.

```
var intervalCounter = 0, intervalId = 0;
var intervalDelay = 10000; // Time in milliseconds
var popupWindow = null, popupWindowURL = "http://www.google.com";
var urlIndex = 0;
var urlList = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.youtube.com",
    "http://www.yahoo.com"
];
function refreshPopup() {
    if (popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed) {
        //popupWindow.location.reload(); // Some browsers may not allow this
        popupWindow.location.href = popupWindowURL;
    }
    if (intervalId && (++intervalCounter) > 5) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        intervalCounter = 0;
    }
}
// User clicked on the page somewhere
document.body.onclick=function() {
    // If no popup window exists, then create it
    if (!popupWindow || popupWindow.closed) {
        urlIndex = urlIndex < urlList.length ? urlIndex : 0;
        popupWindowURL = urlList[urlIndex]
        urlIndex++;
        popupWindow = window.open(popupWindowURL, 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 5, top = 5');
    }
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = setInterval(refreshPopup, intervalDelay); //
}
```

Comment: Can't it be passed in either way? I know it works when passing it in as a string (including the parens).

Comment: first thank you for help but the code doesn't work after add

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
}
document.body.onclick=function() {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', 'poppage', 'toolbars=0, scrollbars=1, location=0, statusbars=0, menubars=0, resizable=1, width=950, height=650, left = 5, top = 5');
    setInterval("doSomething()", 10000);
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="button" onclick="">
</body>
</html>

Comment: @KenF.InnesIV - What should be done is `setInterval(doSomething, 10000)`. Function reference should be passed instead of a String since it is not safe in some cases.

Comment: The window.open code should go inside the doSomething() function

Comment: Something bothers me with this incomplete solution. If the user clicks 10 times on the body, it'll execute it more and more often.

Comment: Good point, I have added a line to the sample code to prevent that.

Comment: thank you primehalo
your code is very good,the first pressure works well But when the close-ups and click again on the page Google Chrome prevents pop-up window.

Comment: You are right, Google Chrome will prevent pop-up windows from opening too many times. There's nothing that you or I can do about that, only the end user can click the anti-popup notification icon in Google Chrome's address bar to allow all pop-ups.

Comment: OK no problem
I have another request I hope that will help me. 
Are you unable to make the update pop-up window to ten times just because it is refreshes continuously. 
Much obliged.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're asking. If you want the popup window to open once and then refresh it every ten seconds, I don't think that is possible. I think the browser would prevent that for security reasons.

Comment: I just did a test. I assigned the popup window to the variable `popupWindow` and did `popupWindow.location.reload()` and it didn't work. But `popupWindow.location.href="http://www.google.com"` did work.

Comment: I mean when i click anywhere on the page, open a new window. 
This window refreshes every ten seconds continuously. This is good. 
I do not want it refreshes continuously,I want it refreshes five or ten times only.

If you do not understand me, I will work video on the YouTube.

Comment: I added code that will open a popup window when the document is clicked, then "refresh" it 5 times every 10 seconds

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you mind marking my answer as the accepted answer? What do you mean by post a random sites list? Do you want a random site from a list to open in the new window?

Comment: thank you very much again.
I am very happy to be here with you.
yes,I want a random site from a list to open in the new window or from the list of sites in order without random like(google.com then youtube.com then yahoo.com then starts again google.com then...) .
"+1"

Comment: I have added a list of URLs. It will pick the next URL in the listonly when a new popup is opened.

Comment: Wow
thank you very much.
I have searched for code like this for a week in Google and did not find it. 
The good fortune to have entered into this site. Luckily, you answered me. 
I want to vote you +1. How do I work? 
When the vote (up) on the site says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Yes, you need 15 reputation points to vote up. This page explains reputation points: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: oh yes,i understand.thank you very much agian. good bye my friends

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this using jQuery.

```
$(function() {
  $('html').on('click', function(){
    $.setTimeout(function() {
      // do something every 10 seconds after the first click.
    }, 10000);
  });
});
```

Of course you'll have to include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in pure javascript, although I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve:

```
var running=false, timeout;
document.body.onclick= toggleScript;

function toggleScript(){
    running=!running;
    if(!running) clearTimeout(timeout);
    else doTheLoop();
}

function doTheLoop(){
    /* Do something */
    timeout = setTimeout(doTheLoop,10000);
}
```

### JS Fiddle example

#### Edit

Click [**here**](http://jsbin.com/tozilixi/2) to see it run with your code (window.open).